# Angular JS Angular UI Google Map Load Order

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Trying to work out why this JSFiddle Works i.e the Marker is displayed as MapIdle() is triggered successfully: http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/9kF7d/

```
$scope.onMapIdle = function() {
    if ($scope.myMarkers === undefined){    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: ll
        });
        $scope.myMarkers = [marker, ];
    }
};
```

but in this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wPFtWSpjj0MwxqaQ7bh3?p=preview with the same code the MapIdle() Function is not triggered.

I'm guessing it something to do with the load order of the External scripts setup in JSFiddle.

Can anyone shed some light on this and/or get that Plnkr working

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add JQUERY to your plunker which was already there in fiddle but not in plunker just add

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

to your plunker its works, and also make sure you import jquery first and other JS files later

Here is the [WORKING PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zd9GwG?p=preview)